# How do I find value of $i^{1/i}$ and $i^{\sqrt{i}}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I find value of $i^{1/i}$ and $i^{\sqrt{i}}$ ?

Comment: First you should expand (simplify) your exponents, then define what you mean by complex number raised to the complex power: it's not a single-valued function in general.

Comment: Hint: [Euler's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity):
$$e^{i\theta}=\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}$$
Try to make the RHS equal to $i$ by changing $\theta$.

Comment: Just as an alternative: $i^{\frac{1}{i}}=i^{-1}=\frac{1}{i^i}=\frac{1}{(e^{i\pi /2})^i}=\frac{1}{e^{i^2\pi /2}}=\frac{1}{e^{-\pi /2}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{e^{\pi /2}}}=e^{\pi /2}=\sqrt{e^\pi}$

Answer (score 4):

Replace $i=e^{i\pi/2}$.

The first one becomes $$\left(e^{i\pi/2}\right)^{1/i}=e^{\pi/2}$$

The second one:
$$\begin{align}
{e^{i\pi/2}}^{(e^{i\pi/4})}&={e^{i\pi/2}}^{(\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4))}\\
&=e^{i\pi/2(\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4))}\\
&=e^{i(\pi/2)\cos(\pi/4)-(\pi/2)\sin(\pi/4)}\\
&=\frac{e^{i(\pi/2)\cos(\pi/4)}}{e^{(\pi/2)\sin(\pi/4)}}\\
&=\frac{\cos((\pi/2)\cos(\pi/4))+i\sin((\pi/2)\cos(\pi/4))}{e^{(\pi/2)\sin(\pi/4)}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Why is i equal to that?

Comment: @Azra See my hint, that answers your question about why $i=e^{i\pi/2}$.

Comment: The Euler formula is $e^{i\pi/2}=\cos(\pi/2)+i\sin(\pi/2)=0+i=i$.

Comment: $sin(\pi/4)=cos(\pi/4)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ if further simplification is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that the second one is

$$i^{\sqrt{i}}=i^{(1+i) \sqrt{2}/2}=e^{i\pi/2 \cdot (1+i) \sqrt{2}/2}=e^{\sqrt{2}/4 \cdot \pi(-1+i) }$$

I have checked numerically and find this is equivalent to $i^{\sqrt{i}}$ as well as the result of @msm.